# Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53], When connecting to two databases on same server

Tags: java, sql-server, database, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create two database connections using JdbcTemplate in spring MVC. I have two databases on same test server. when I try to connect both at same time the second connection throws error

> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53].

Surprisingly when I connect one with test DB server and another with production DB server, both connections work. I don't know what actually causing it.

Spring-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pr.pct.beans" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pr.pct.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pr.pct.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pr.pct.controller" />



    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>



     <bean id="dataSourceDR" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;DatabaseName=DB1;"/> 
            <property name="username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="password" value="123123"/>
   </bean>



   <bean id="dataSource" 
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;Database=DB2;"/>
            <property name="username" value="sa"/>
      <property name="password" value="123123"/>

  </bean> 




 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />    
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

JdbcTemplate DAO

```
package com.pr.pct.dao;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ConnectionDao {

    private DataSource dataSource;
    private DataSource dataSourceDR;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = null;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateDR = null;

    public DataSource getDataSourceDR() {
        return dataSourceDR;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSourceDR(DataSource dataSourceDR) {
        jdbcTemplateDR = new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceDR);
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplateDR() {
        return jdbcTemplateDR;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplateDR(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateDR) {
        this.jdbcTemplateDR = jdbcTemplateDR;
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

Stored Procedure Execution

```
@Autowired
ConnectionDao connectionDao;

then in  function


connectionDao.getJdbcTemplateDR().queryForRowSet("USP_PCT_StartCurrentBookings"); -- calling procedure
```

`

Comment: I see in datasource bean there's no port, is that typo? -> value="jdbc:sqlserver://IP1433;Database=DB2;"

Comment: @Erwin yeah. ":" mistakenly removed while posting question.

Comment: both database in same location just different schema?

Comment: @Erwin Yes, only schema is different.

Comment: why don't u use call for the stored procedure? "call USP_PCT_StartCurrentBookings". is it working? may be you can try put schema name in front of the SP "call DB1. USP_PCT_StartCurrentBookings"